# Typescript value type in generic type

Tags: typescript

I have generic type that makes field required

```
type MakeFieldRequired<T, K extends keyof T> =
    T & Required<Pick<T, K>>

type Data = {
    optional1?: number;
    optional2?: number;
    required: number;
}

const data: Data = {
    required: 1
}

const data2: MakeFieldRequired<Data, 'optional1'> = {
    optional1: 1,
    required: 1
};
```

How do I make generic and use value type there directly, something like

```
type MakeOptional2FieldRequired<T>
    = MakeFieldRequired<T, T['optional2']>;

const data3: MakeOptional2FieldRequired<Data> = {
    optional2: 1,
    required: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the type of `T['optional2']` you'd set a constraint on `T`.

```js
type MakeOptional2FieldRequired<T extends { optional2: any }> = T['optional2']
```

But I don't think that's actually what you want here as that will pass the *type* as the property key. Instead, just pass the string literal

```
type MakeOptional2FieldRequired<T extends { optional2: any }> = MakeFieldRequired<T, 'optional2'>
```

Comment: This uses any so the optional2 type would not get inferred correctly i guess?

Comment: @PetrHurtak this is a constraint that says T must have a property of `optional2`, but the value can be anything. `T` itself will be a concrete type though and the resulting type will be inferred correctly.